# Преобразовать base64 в файл Node js/js

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64

У меня есть json файл который нужно загрузить на сервер, для раздачи статики.

Все бы ничего но сам файл весит 89мб из-за картинок которые хранятся base64. Можно ли каким то образом их преобразовать в png или как то декодировать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38935990/7692602

Comment: Есть модуль для преобразования "строк base64" в картинки (файлы)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-to-image

Comment: покажите пример данных, в каком виде в файле хранятся картинки?

Comment: @nörbörnën
 https://imgur.com/a/Hw4IieL то что подчеркнул зеленым является base 64 картинкой, их очень много)